# Is there a possibility to make a field blank while inserting a string when a field is NaN?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, nan

I have the following array:

```
a = np.array([np.nan, str(606194584), str(20203229)])
a
>>array([nan,  606194584,  202032291.])

for rows in a:
    if i == np.NaN:
        print("")
else:
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Document Type': df['Factuurnummer'].astype(str) + """<?xml version="1.0"?>"""})
print(df3)
                    Document Type
0           <?xml version="1.0"?>
1  606194584<?xml version="1.0"?>
2  202032291<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Desired output:

```
               Document Type
0  
1  606194584<?xml version="1.0"?>       
2  202032291<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

So I'm looking to do this for each column in a df. Please help I've been chewing away at this for the past hours hahaa

Answer (score 0):

In python, `NaN` != `NaN`. That's how it works for most floating point numbers, as it's part of the IEEE-754 spec.

```
>>> float("NaN")
nan
>>> float("NaN") == float("NaN")
False
```

so instead of using `if i == np.nan` you should use `if np.isnan(i)`

Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: at that point I suggest you review your code. I didn't pay too much attention, but you use `for rows in a`, and then compare with `i`. Which is it? Is the variable `i` or `rows`?

Comment: It's a, because I have to extract the values from a.

Comment: Can you please help me?